# Adjusting bootstrap 3 bootbox.js modal to open in the same spot

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

Right now when you click a portfolio item the page scrolls up and then the modal opens how can I adjust it so the page stays in the same place?

I am using bootbox.js and bootstrap 3, you can check out [**what Im talking about here**](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/) (just scroll down to portfolio and click one of the images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your anchor `<a>` tags change the href attribute to `javascript:void(0);`, like this snippet of code.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="branding3">
                        <img src="img/projects/thumbs/branding3.jpg" alt="...">
                        <span class="portfolio-hover">
                          <span>
                            <h4>Synex</h4>
                            <em>Branding</em>
                          </span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
```

Currently you have some pound symbol (**#**) within your *anchor* tags' href in which does not point to any id attribute in your tags. That is why the page scrolls directly to the top when you click those links.

Comment: I ran into another issue which makes this solution not work anymore! I have been trying to figure it out for a whole day if you want to [take a look at my new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546885/bootbox-js-modal-not-scrolling-scrolling-background) for some extra points :)